# No se puede acceder a la memoria con un iterator a un map

Tags: c++, diccionarios, map

Tengo definida la siguiente clase

```
class Especie {

private:

string id;
string gen;
map<string,int> kmer;
static int k;

public: ...
};
```

Después de llenar el diccionario `map<string,Especie>desp;` quiero acceder al contenido del último elemento de desp y lo hago con un iterator

```
map<string,Especie>::const_iterator it = desp.end(); 
--it;
```

Pero al chequear el contenido apuntado por it con un depurador me sale

```
{first = <error: Cannot access memory at address 0x5>, second = {
id = "", gen = "", kmer = std::map with 140737488346464 elements<error reading variable:
Cannot access memory at address 0x18>, static k = 5}}
```

Mientras que si chequeo el contenido del último elemento del diccionario me sale (y es lo correcto)

```
{["e"] = {id = "e", gen = "TACACCATTAACCGGTGGGG", kmer = std::map with 16 elements = {
      ["AACCG"] = 1, ["ACACC"] = 1, ["ACCAT"] = 1, ["ACCGG"] = 1, ["ATTAA"] = 1, ["CACCA"] = 1, 
      ["CATTA"] = 1, ["CCATT"] = 1, ["CCGGT"] = 1, ["CGGTG"] = 1, ["GGTGG"] = 1, ["GTGGG"] = 1, 
      ["TAACC"] = 1, ["TACAC"] = 1, ["TGGGG"] = 1, ["TTAAC"] = 1}, static k = 5}}
```

Alguien sabe porqué el iterator me da esos errores de memoria?

Comment: Por favor, muestra un ejemplo mínimo que reproduzca el problema

Answer (score 1):

Estás depurando mal. Seguramente miras el iterador antes de decrementarlo, suponiendo que `[*]` es el punto de interrupción:

```
    map<string,Especie>::const_iterator it = desp.end(); 
[*] --it;
```

Cuando el depurador se para en la línea `--it`, aún no se ha ejecutado la sentencia, prueba esto:

```
    map<string,Especie>::const_iterator it = desp.end(); 
    --it;
[*] std::cout << "Chivato\n";
```

Examina el contenido de `it` cuando has pasado la línea en que lo decrementas.

Comment: El contenido de ìt` lo examino después de pasar la línea `--it;`. De hecho en la lincea anterior no me deja examinarlo porque dice que no se puede desreferenciar el iterado.

Comment: Pues debería funcionar ([ver código](https://wandbox.org/permlink/DMUN3fIyGWbbjvzZ)), o no lo haces exactamente como dices o hay algo que no estás mostrando.

Comment: Pues debe de estar en otra parte el error. Lo que veo es que si hago `map<string,Especie>::const_iterator aux = desp.rbegin()`me da error `conversion to non-scalar type`. Soy bastante nuevo en programación, pero me temo que esto no tendría porqué dar error, no? Puede que esto me esté dando alguna pista de dónde está el verdadero error?

Comment: `rbegin` es un `reverse_iterator`, obviamente no puede ser asignado a un `const_iterator`.

Comment: Okey, lo prové con `reverse_iterator` y efectivamente igual que con el `--desp.end()` me dice que no se puede acceder a memoria. Pero en cambio si hago  `map<string,Especie>* p = &desp;` y compruebo el contenido de p me sale correctamente el contenido del diccionario. Es decir el problema lo tengo al intentar acceder a uno de los elementos en concreto, como se explica eso?

Comment: ¿No estarás depurando con las opciones de optimización activadas, por ejemplo, en modo *release* en lugar de en modo *debug*?

Comment: Pues no lo sé la verdad. Como ya he dicho soy bastante nuevo, y no sé de qué me hablas. De todas formas ya he conseguido resolver el problema. Gracias a que me confirmaste que la parte de los iteradores estaba bién, me centré en buscar el error por otras partes y hoy por fin lo he encontrado. Te agradezco mucho el tiempo que me has dedicado.